# how to map expression<func<Entity,DTO>> with automapper

Tags: c#, linq, expression, automapper, func

CreateMap

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Unidade, unidadeDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<unidadeDTO, Unidade>();




public ICollection<Unidade> BuscarPorParametos(Expression<Func<Unidade, bool>> parametros)
{
    return Mapper.Map<ICollection<unidadeDTO>, ICollection<Unidade>>(unidadeDeTrabalho.UnidadeDAO.BuscarPorParametros(Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Unidade, bool>>, Expression<Func<unidadeDTO, bool>>>(parametros)));
}
```

Automapper exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Expression`1 -> Expression`1
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`2[[Unidade, Dominio,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] ->
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`2[[unidadeDTO,
>   Infraestrutura, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>
> Destination path: Expression`1

Source value:
p => ((p.CodUnidade == 1) AndAlso (p.CodTrabalho == 1))

Comment: I don't think you can use automapper on `Expression`s. You normally use the expressions as part of queries, then automap the results of those queries to different classes.

Comment: Can you show the `CreateMap` statements?

Comment: Mapper.CreateMap<Unidade, unidadeDTO>(); 
Mapper.CreateMap<unidadeDTO, Unidade>();

Comment: OK, so you want to map regular objects. What are you trying to achieve with the second `Mapper.Map` statement? Right now, you're trying to copy an expression to another expression, but you clearly don't intend to do that (and it's impossible).

Comment: alright.
i need mapping filter from repository to dao.

Comment: Please be more specific. How would you achieve your goal without AutoMapper? That would really clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

When working with Expressions and AutoMapper you need to use the [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) namespace.

It uses a different syntax than normal auto-mapper. Normally you would use it in line with your query to get the resultset you want.

```
//---- Declared elsewhere
Mapper.CreateMap<Unidade, unidadeDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<unidadeDTO, Unidade>();
//----

public static IQueryable<unidadeDTO> ConvertToDTO(IQueryable<Unidade> source)
{
    return source.Project().To<unidadeDTO>();
}
```

Now you can write filters expressions against the new IQueryable and the changes will be propagated back up to the original SQL. This allows you to do things like this

```
public class OrderLine
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public Item Item { get; set; }
  public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineDTO
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
  public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDAL
{
    static OrderDAL()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<OrderLine, OrderLineDTO>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ItemName, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Item.Name);
    }

    public List<OrderLineDTO> GetLinesForOrder(string itemName)
    {
      using (var context = new orderEntities())
      {
        return context.OrderLines.Project().To<OrderLineDTO>()
               .Where(i => i.ItemName == itemName).ToList();
      }
    }
}
```

Notice how I am using the property `ItemName` of the DTO to perform the filtering.